# How can I get a recognition between two flowers?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 'red';
var y = 'yellow';
var tulip = 'red';
var sunflower = 'yellow';
if (sunflower === 'yellow')
{
    console.log("The flower is sunflower");
} else
{
    console.log("This is not a sunflower");
}
if (tulip === 'red')
{
    console.log("The flower is tulip");
} else
{
    console.log("This is not a tulip");
}
```

Comment: Explain a little more of what are you trying achieve and whats not working.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Improve your question.

Comment: What you mean by `between two flowers` ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to review the [guidelines on asking a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I suggest you first look at the section entitled "Introduce the problem before you post any code".

Comment: This is a class assignment..I cannot go further..I need to make it recognized between two flowers only a red tulip and a yellow sunflower..it can look like anything, such as having two flower pictures, user clicking on one( or just on a red colour box for instance) and get idetified as tulip..thank you for quick responses ..this is amazing

Answer (score 1):

To distinguish the type of flower by color, meaning you need to have a flower object with just a color property, without you knowing the actual flower type.

So we create a flower class, assign it a color, and check to see the type of flower.

you can in turn also create a type property to your object(the flower), and preset the flower with its type.

Heres a short demonstration of creating 2 flowers with a color, putting them in an array, and then checking the types of the flowers.

https://jsfiddle.net/55c01zde/

```
var red = 'red';
var yellow = 'yellow';

function flower(color) {
    this.color = color;
}

var firstFlower = new flower(red);
var secondFlower = new flower(yellow);

var flowers = [firstFlower, secondFlower];

flowers.forEach(function (flower, index) {
    var displayIndex = index +1;
    switch (flower.color) {
        case red:
            console.log("flower number " + displayIndex + " is a tulip");
            break;
        case yellow:
            console.log("flower number " + displayIndex + " is a sunflower");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ofer Haber a billion..this is a great start

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will guide you in the right direction?

```
var colors = ["yellow", "red"];
var flowers = ["sunflower", "tulip"];

function choice (color) {
    if (color == colors[0]) {
        return ("The flower is a " + flowers[0]);
    } else if (color == colors[1]) {
        return ("The flower is a " + flowers[1]);
    }
    else {
        return ("This is not a flower");
    }
}

document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML = choice("red");
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/fpsaafj2/2/